# How does scope work in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

Why does this code throw an error in the if block, 
`ReferenceError: x is not defined`? I understand it looks wrong to define another variable called x, but shouldn't it be throwing the error when defining the new const x?

```
'use strict'

function task() {
    const x = 5
    return _subTask({x, condition: true})
}


function _subTask({x, condition}) {
    if (condition) {
        const y = x * 10
        const x = y * 10
        return x
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
console.log(task())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have here called temporal dead zone (TDZ). According to ES6, if there is let or const in the block. Before let or const declarison, the variable can not been accessed.

```
{
   // TDZ start here
   // x can not been accessed
   const y = x * 10
   const x = y * 10
   return x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the **Temporal Dead Zone (TDZ)**. When a `let` or a `const` variable is accessed which is defined in the later part of the code, it is said to be in TDZ and a `ReferenceError` will be thrown. `let` and `const` variables don't hoist. You can read more about TDZ in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

In your case, you mean to use the value of `x` from the function's parameters in the statement `const y = x * 10` I assume. Since you have declared `x` locally in that scope, that takes higher precedence. As `x` is in TDZ when the control reaches `const y = x * 10`, accessing it throws that error.

To fix this you need to use a different variable name instead of `x` in either of the places. As a general good practice, always use unique variable names.

---

In your specific case, unless you need the `_subtask` function to be called from multiple places, you can simplify your `task` implementation like this

```
function task() {
  const x = 5;
  return (condition ? x * 100 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand it looks wrong to define another variable called x, but
>   shouldn't it be throwing the error when defining the new const x?

`x` being a `const` cannot be accessed before it is `defined` **in that if block**.

However, it can be accessed before that `if`

```js
function task() 
{
    const x = 5
    return _subTask({x, condition: true})
}
function _subTask({x, condition}) 
{
    console.log(x); //this will print fine 
    if (condition) {
        const y = x * 10 //also this will  give an error
        const x = y * 10
        return x
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
console.log(task())
```

You can modify your code (without `const`) as

```
function _subTask({x, condition}) 
{
    return condition ? (x * 10 * 10) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (condition) {
    const y = x * 10;
    {
      const x = y * 10
      return x;
    }
}
```

That works as `x` in the `y` declaration now refers to the destructured param, as the local definition is enclosed in another block.